# Select mismatched column values from Two Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two tables which has same column names.

For example:

**NEEDTOSYNCREQUESTS** table

```
Column Name         Value
----------------------------
ID                  1
LoadId              L1 
ShipmentId          123 
OrderId             NULL
PackageId           P456 
CustomerOTP         99999
ClientOTP           88888
```

**LASTSYNCEDREQUEST** table:

```
Column Name         Value
-------------------------
ID                  1
LoadId              L1 
ShipmentId          NULL
OrderId             1234567
PackageId           P456 
CustomerOTP         44444
ClientOTP           686868
```

If you compare the above table's column valuesy You could see the following:

1. CustomerOTP & ClientOTP columns values are not identical.
2. ShipmentId Column in NEEDTOSYNCREQUESTS has value and ShipmentId Column in LASTSYNCEDREQUEST Table is NULL.
3. OrderId Column in LASTSYNCEDREQUEST Table has value and ShipmentId Column in NEEDTOSYNCREQUESTS Table is NULL.

So, I need to get the following output. How to achieve this?

**OUTPUT**

```
Column Name         Value
---------------------------------
ID                  1
LoadId              NULL 
ShipmentId          123 
OrderId             NULL
PackageId           NULL
CustomerOTP         99999
ClientOTP           88888
```

The condition is, I need to compare the above two tables and needed only the updated column values  NEEDTOSYNCREQUESTS Table when compared with another  LASTSYNCEDREQUEST Table. Note: Both the columns have same values or  NEEDTOSYNCREQUESTS Table Column does not have values then those columns should be null in the Output. PackageId in both the Table is Identical(same). So, I need PackageId to be NULL in the output.

Please help me to achieve this in a SQL query.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about the last two fields? How did Packageid become NULL?

Comment: What you have tried so far ? and what is the outcome of that.

Comment: @Vashi Packageid in both the Table is Identical(same). So, I need PackageId to be NULL in the output

Comment: And tables are matched on ID, is that right?

Comment: @Vashi you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, the same rules implemented in 3 WHENs in a CASE statement for all fields.

```
SELECT A.ID,
CASE WHEN A.LOADID = B.LOADID THEN NULL
     WHEN A.LOADID IS NULL THEN NULL
     WHEN (B.LOADID IS NULL AND A.LOADID IS NOT NULL) OR (A.LOADID IS NOT NULL AND B.LOADID IS NOT NULL) THEN A.LOADID END AS LOADID,
CASE WHEN A.SHIPMENTID = B.SHIPMENTID THEN NULL
     WHEN A.SHIPMENTID IS NULL THEN NULL
     WHEN (B.SHIPMENTID IS NULL AND A.SHIPMENTID IS NOT NULL) OR (A.SHIPMENTID IS NOT NULL AND B.SHIPMENTID IS NOT NULL) THEN A.SHIPMENTID END AS SHIPMENTID,
CASE WHEN A.ORDERID = B.ORDERID THEN NULL
     WHEN A.ORDERID IS NULL THEN NULL
     WHEN (B.ORDERID IS NULL AND A.ORDERID IS NOT NULL) OR (A.ORDERID IS NOT NULL AND B.ORDERID IS NOT NULL) THEN A.ORDERID END AS ORDERID,
CASE WHEN A.PACKAGEID = B.PACKAGEID THEN NULL
     WHEN A.PACKAGEID IS NULL THEN NULL
     WHEN (B.PACKAGEID IS NULL AND A.PACKAGEID IS NOT NULL) OR (A.PACKAGEID IS NOT NULL AND B.PACKAGEID IS NOT NULL) THEN A.PACKAGEID END AS PACKAGEID,
CASE WHEN A.CUSTOMEROTP = B.CUSTOMEROTP THEN NULL
     WHEN A.CUSTOMEROTP IS NULL THEN NULL
     WHEN (B.CUSTOMEROTP IS NULL AND A.CUSTOMEROTP IS NOT NULL) OR (A.CUSTOMEROTP IS NOT NULL AND B.CUSTOMEROTP IS NOT NULL) THEN A.CUSTOMEROTP END AS CUSTOMEROTP,
CASE WHEN A.CLIENTOTP = B.CLIENTOTP THEN NULL
     WHEN A.CLIENTOTP IS NULL THEN NULL
     WHEN (B.CLIENTOTP IS NULL AND A.CLIENTOTP IS NOT NULL) OR (A.CLIENTOTP IS NOT NULL AND B.CLIENTOTP IS NOT NULL) THEN A.CLIENTOTP END AS CLIENTOTP
FROM
NEEDTOSYNCREQUESTS A
INNER JOIN
LASTSYNCEDREQUEST B
ON A.ID = B.ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try a case based query like below
<kbd>**[See live demo](http://rextester.com/PWP28954)**</kbd>

```
select
    id      = N.id,
    Loadid  = case 
                when ISNULL(N.Loadid,'')=ISNULL(L.Loadid,'') 
                then NULL
                else N.LoadId
              end,
    Shipmentid=case 
                when ISNULL(N.Shipmentid,'')=ISNULL(L.Shipmentid,'') 
                then NULL
                else N.Shipmentid
              end,
    orderid=case 
                when ISNULL(N.orderid,'')=ISNULL(L.orderid,'') 
                then NULL
                else N.orderid
              end,
    packageid=case 
                when ISNULL(N.packageid,'')=ISNULL(L.packageid,'') 
                then NULL
                else N.packageid
              end,
    customerOTP=case 
                when ISNULL(N.customerOTP,'')=ISNULL(L.customerOTP,'') 
                then NULL
                else N.customerOTP
              end,
    clientOTP=case 
                when ISNULL(N.clientOTP,'')=ISNULL(L.clientOTP,'') 
                then NULL
                else N.clientOTP
              end
from
NEEDTOSYNCREQUESTS N LEFT JOIN
LASTSYNCEDREQUEST L ON
N.id=L.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT n.ID, n.LoadId, n.ShipmentId,
  n.OrderId, NULL PackageId, n.CustomerOTP,
  n.ClientOTP
FROM NEEDTOSYNCREQUESTS AS n
INNER JOIN LASTSYNCEDREQUEST AS l ON n.ID = l.ID AND n.LoadId = l.LoadId
WHERE n.CustomerOTP <> l.CustomerOTP AND
      n.ClientOTP   <> l.ClientOTP
  AND n.ShipmentId IS NOT NULL
  AND l.ShipmentId IS NULL
  AND l.OrderId IS NOT NULL
  AND l.ShipmentId IS NULL;
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fd14b/2)

```
| ID | LoadId | ShipmentId | OrderId | PackageId | CustomerOTP | ClientOTP |
|----|--------|------------|---------|-----------|-------------|-----------|
|  1 |     L1 |        123 |  (null) |    (null) |       99999 |     88888 |
```

Note that, I don't understand why the `PackageId` should be null, because according to your criteria, it shouldn't. Anyway, I select it as a fixed `NULL` value, so that you will always get a `NULL` value no matter what is the actual value.

Answer (score 0):

I often have to solve some case like this when creating data extraction or integration.

So the answer for me will be close to this :

you can use the **MERGE** function and add some switch case if you want to custom it for some column

```
MERGE LASTSYNCEDREQUEST TGT
USING (
 SELECT 
  ID,
  LoadId,
  ShipmentId,
  OrderId,
  PackageId,
  CustomerOTP,
  ClientOTP

FROM NEEDTOSYNCREQUESTS
) AS SRC
ON (
        SRC.ID = TGT.ID)

WHEN MATCHED
THEN
    UPDATE
    SET     
     TGT.ID = SRC.ID
    ,TGT.LoadID = NULL
    ,TGT.ShipmentID = SRC.ShipmentID
    ,TGT.OrderID = NULL
    ,TGT.PackageID = NULL
    ,TGT.CustomerOTP = SRC.CustomerOTP
    ,TGT.ClientOTP = SRC.ClientOTP


WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN
    INSERT (

        ID,
        LoadId,
        ShipmentId,
        OrderId,
        PackageId,
        CustomerOTP,
        ClientOTP

        )
    VALUES (
         SRC.ID,
         NULL,
         SRC.ShipmentId,
         NULL,
         NULL,
         SRC.CustomerOTP,
         SRC.ClientOTP

        );

SELECT * FROM LASTSYNCEDREQUEST
```

you can try the code that I write above.